# How can I use `Class.forName()` to get classes defined in a `ToolBox`?

Tags: scala, reflection, classloader, toolbox

I'm trying to use Scala reflection (namely a `ToolBox`) to generate a class at runtime for use with a library that will access it reflectively with `Class.forName("MyClass")`

Is this possible?

I expected that this would work (in 2.10.3 with Macro Paradise for the quasiquotes):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm}

def cdef() = q"case class MyClass(x: String)"
def newc(csym: Symbol) = q"""new ${csym.asClass}("hello")"""
val tb   = cm.mkToolBox()
val csym = tb.define(cdef())
val obj  = tb.eval(newc(csym))
val cls  = Class.forName("MyClass")
```

But that returns an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)...
```

(The toolbox returns a class in a wrapper, and so I've also tried using the full name, but no luck.)

And so I suspect that I'm misunderstanding how to get `Toolbox` to use the same classloader as `Class.forName()`

How can I use `Class.forName()` to get classes defined in a `ToolBox`?

Any insight is appreciated,
-Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toolboxes evaluate code in uniquely named packages in order to sidestep tricky naming problems. Moreover, the code to be evaluated is also put into a synthetic method of a synthetic module, so all the classes become local classes. This is why `Class.forName` doesn't work.

In order to get hold of the class, how about doing eval on `class C(...); classOf[C]`? That will return a `j.l.Class` that you're looking for. In 2.11.x, there's an alternative of using `Toolbox.define`, which defines top-level classes and modules and returns the symbols defined, but in 2.10.x I don't think there's much to be done without `classOf`.

Comment: I'm using [your gist](https://gist.github.com/xeno-by/5845539) to get `define` in 2.10.3, so I believe my classes are top-level. I still should expect to be unable to access them with `Class.forName`? I appreciate your alternate suggestions but I do not have immediate control to use something besides `Class.forName`.

Comment: I'm afk at the moment, but as far as I remember, define still puts the classes you provide in a uniquely named package, so using an unqualified name won't work. Otoh, define returns a class or module symbol, so you should be able to figure out the name of the enclosing package by traversing the owner chain.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same exception: [error] (run-main-f) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package __wrapper$75da044aa1e44009afdf256849cb55ca.C
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package __wrapper$75da044aa1e44009afdf256849cb55ca.C
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)...
Tried in 2.11 as well, and was using your 2.10.3 gist so I could experiment with different enclosing package names, but still no luck. Dunno if it's related, but `C$` can't be found either, when I try to get one with `instance` on a `ModuleMirror`. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Oh, right, toolbox has a special classloader that holds generated class files in memory...

Comment: Here's how you can get to it: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/73fb460c1cd20ee97556ec0867d17efaa795d129/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/ToolBoxFactory.scala#L31 (not in the public api, so you'll have to do reflection)

Comment: Thanks. I tried Scala reflection:
`val tbType = ru.typeOf[scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl]
val termName = ru.newTermName("classLoader”)
val field = t.declaration(termName).asTerm.accessed.asTerm`

But calling `accessed` returns:
`java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: value classLoader at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.accessed(Symbols.scala:1978)…`

Comment: I tried:
`val loader = (tb.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl].classLoader)
Class.forName(csym.owner + “.C”, true, loader)`

I can get the classLoader, but I can’t find the class there either (I get the same exception as when I use Java reflection to get the loader):
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package __wrapper$1$f4ea824a6e3449ebb8c151d5da390021.C at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:85) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)…`

Any ideas on why I still am not able to find the class?

Comment: You need to do `csym.owner.fullName + ".C"`, not just `csym.owner`, because toString of a symbol also includes its designation, i.e. "package", "object", etc.

Comment: RE: "tricky naming problems", If I were to use your gist to give the wrapper package a "normal" name, are there any precautions that I can take to keep things hygienic? E.g., would it be sufficient to check all known classloaders to see if the gen'd names have already been used?

Comment: The problem is not just with the classes explicitly created by the user. There are also synthetics like anonfun$1 and likes that can bubble up to the top level and really ruin your day. That's actually the main reason to have crazily named packages.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, given that my gen'd classes are simple case classes with only fields (of Scala data types), I believe there are no gen'd synthetics that will pollute the namespace. I saw the [note](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/ToolBoxFactory.scala#L53), and since I'm not spawning toolboxes within toolboxes, I experimented further with "normal" package names. Any idea why toolbox compilation fails if I try to generate a second class with the same package name? [[Runnable Example](http://bit.ly/1rtPGAW)].

Comment: And if one gen'd class is in test and the other in main, whichever is run first works, and the second one's toolbox compilation fails. This remains the case upon re-runs,  `clean` and `reload`, but is reset when sbt is restarted.

Comment: [The error](https://github.com/julianpeeters/toolbox-salat-example/blob/two_classes_error/src/main/scala/Main.scala#L59)

Comment: Allright, I've figured out what's wrong. The problem is with the importer that brings the symbols from the toolbox universe into the scala.reflect.runtime universe. The results of importing are cached, so if an imported symbol already exists in the target universe, then the importer skips it. Unfortunately this means that if a package symbol already exists in the runtime universe, then the importer won't go through its children and import them recursively.

Comment: This explains why it works the first time, but not the second time. The first time the `pkg` symbol doesn't exist, so the importer brings all its children into the runtime universe (both class C and object C). The second time it exists, so only the child that's explicitly requested to be imported (class D) is imported, and the rest are left alone.

Comment: Good thing that in scala.meta we no longer have different universes, so these kinds of problems are impossible.